# How to change a date picker field based on the radio button selection using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this piece of HTML where I have 5 radio selection. Based on the radio selection the end date should update the custom_41 field.
If I select 12 months radio the date field should update to 12 months from today, similarly for all 24 months etc.
Can someone help please? Thanks

```js
$('#CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
$('#custom_41').val(today);  
      }
})
```

```html
<div class="crm-section editrow_custom_39-section form-item" id="editrow-custom_39" style="display: block !important; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="label">
          <label>Monthly Interval</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          
                                    <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval" data-api-entity="Contact" data-api-field="custom_39" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval" class="crm-form-radio" value="1" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39" name="custom_39"><label for="CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39">12 Months</label>
                                    <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval" data-api-entity="Contact" data-api-field="custom_39" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval" class="crm-form-radio" value="2" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2_custom_39" name="custom_39"><label for="CIVICRM_QFID_2_custom_39">24 Months</label>
                                    <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval" data-api-entity="Contact" data-api-field="custom_39" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval" class="crm-form-radio" value="3" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3_custom_39" name="custom_39"><label for="CIVICRM_QFID_3_custom_39">36 Months</label>
                                    <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval" data-api-entity="Contact" data-api-field="custom_39" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval" class="crm-form-radio" value="4" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_4_custom_39" name="custom_39"><label for="CIVICRM_QFID_4_custom_39">48 Months</label>
                                    <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval" data-api-entity="Contact" data-api-field="custom_39" data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval" class="crm-form-radio" value="5" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_5_custom_39" name="custom_39"><label for="CIVICRM_QFID_5_custom_39">60 Months</label>
                      
                            </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="crm-section editrow_custom_41-section form-item" id="editrow-custom_41" style="display: block !important; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="label" style="display: none;">
          <label for="custom_41"> End Date
     <span class="crm-marker" title="This field is required.">*</span>

</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          
                                    <span class="crm-form-date-wrapper"><input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Mandate_End_Date" data-crm-datepicker="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;dd\/mm\/yy&quot;,&quot;minDate&quot;:&quot;2023-01-01&quot;,&quot;maxDate&quot;:null,&quot;time&quot;:false}" aria-label="End Date" name="custom_41" type="text" id="custom_41" class="crm-form-text required crm-hidden-date" placeholder="End Date * " style="display: none;"><input type="text" class="crm-form-text required crm-form-date hasDatepicker" aria-label="End Date" id="dp1698168859281" placeholder="End Date * "></span>
                      
                            </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html code, the input's value has the month value to do it more legible. You needed an OnClick event for the input group only.

```
        <div class="crm-section editrow_custom_39-section form-item" id="editrow-custom_39" style="display: block !important; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="label">
            <label>Monthly Interval</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

            <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval"
                   data-api-entity="Contact"
                   data-api-field="custom_39"
                   data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval"
                   class="crm-form-radio"
                   value="12"
                   type="radio"
                   id="CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39"
                   name="custom_39">
            <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_1_custom_39">12 Months</label>
            <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval"
                   data-api-entity="Contact"
                   data-api-field="custom_39"
                   data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval"
                   class="crm-form-radio"
                   value="24"
                   type="radio"
                   id="CIVICRM_QFID_2_custom_39"
                   name="custom_39">
            <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_2_custom_39">24 Months</label>
            <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval"
                   data-api-entity="Contact"
                   data-api-field="custom_39"
                   data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval"
                   class="crm-form-radio"
                   value="36"
                   type="radio"
                   id="CIVICRM_QFID_3_custom_39"
                   name="custom_39">
            <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_3_custom_39">36 Months</label>
            <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval"
                   data-api-entity="Contact"
                   data-api-field="custom_39"
                   data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval"
                   class="crm-form-radio"
                   value="48"
                   type="radio"
                   id="CIVICRM_QFID_4_custom_39"
                   name="custom_39">
            <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_4_custom_39">48 Months</label>
            <input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Monthly_Interval"
                   data-api-entity="Contact"
                   data-api-field="custom_39"
                   data-option-edit-path="civicrm/admin/options/eNach_Payment_Interval_Monthly_Interval"
                   class="crm-form-radio"
                   value="60"
                   type="radio"
                   id="CIVICRM_QFID_5_custom_39"
                   name="custom_39">
            <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_5_custom_39">60 Months</label>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="crm-section editrow_custom_41-section form-item" id="editrow-custom_41" style="display: block !important; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="label" style="display: none;">
            <label for="custom_41">
                End Date
                <span class="crm-marker" title="This field is required.">*</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

            <span class="crm-form-date-wrapper"><input data-crm-custom="eNach_Payment_Interval:Mandate_End_Date" data-crm-datepicker="{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;dd\/mm\/yy&quot;,&quot;minDate&quot;:&quot;2023-01-01&quot;,&quot;maxDate&quot;:null,&quot;time&quot;:false}" aria-label="End Date" name="custom_41" type="text" id="custom_41" class="crm-form-text required crm-hidden-date" placeholder="End Date * " style="display: none;"><input type="text" class="crm-form-text required crm-form-date hasDatepicker" aria-label="End Date" id="dp1698168859281" placeholder="End Date * "></span>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[name='custom_39']").change(function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var newDate = new Date(now.getFullYear() + (parseInt($(this).val()) / 12), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
            $('#dp1698168859281').val(newDate.toDateString());

        });
    </script>
```